# jQuery TypeError "Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" (function uaMatch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, subdomain

I have a pretty strange problem with jQuery:

I have a website (with Flask) at: `http://localhost:5000/`, it works perfectly. Now I've set up a subdomain, edited my `/etc/hosts` (I added  `127.0.0.1 fonts.localhost`), the subdomain uses exact same html (even less) but when I load the site jQuery gives me this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. It is coming from the function `uaMatch` in line `884` of the uncompressed [jQuery 1.7.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) file. The argument passed to the function must be undefined, uaMatch is just called a single time (line 925) with the `userAgent`, the `userAgent` is assigned at line 75: `userAgent = navigator.userAgent`. `navigator.userAgent` is `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"` (according to the debugging-console).

So I really don't understand why I get this error, which just occurs on the subdomain. The important html of `fonts.localhost:5000`.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://localhost:5000/static/style.css">
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://localhost:5000/static/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:5000/static/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<body>
    …
</body>
```

**EDIT**:
It also doesn't work with jQuery uncompressed (I also included the jQuery files hosted at google for testing, the same error)

Comment: Not sure I get this ? You've set up a site with absolute links to your localhost everywhere, and now you have added a subdomain to your localhost, and edited your windows host file to make it all work together, and you've included jQuery on a site that does not seem to use any javascript, as all you have posted is the HTML, and for some reason it's not working ?

Comment: they are not completly absolute: I am using flask with jinja as template engine, so Flask generates these urls for me and inserts them into the template, so they are absolute but that's not a problem, since I don't have to change them if I move the application to my server. I am on Linux so I edited my `/etc/hosts`, without it, the subdomain isn't resolved properly. The site doesnt use jQuery now, normally it does, I removed all JS to track the error down and to make sure that it's cause by jQuery and not from something else (but good point, I'll minify the html).

Comment: What is in your body? Looks like this error produced while executing some script. Do you have any javascript in body? Try to remove everything in html except `<head>` section with scripts and styles and see if error occures. Such errors happen when jquery (while some script processing) trying to call certain method (in your case `toLowerCase()`) on DOM object and this object is missing.

Comment: No Javascript, the body just contains a navi. Removing everything than the head produces the same error.

Comment: Is your jquery script source original? Try replacing `src` of jQuery library scrit to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Yes it is and I also tried the scripts from google (see Edit)

Comment: What about other browsers? You tried only one?

Comment: The UserAgent above is Chrome/Chromium, but yes I tried Chromium and Mozilla, both gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear, I finally found the error, seems like jQuery can't handle domains with no TLD, I changed the hosts entry from `127.0.0.1 fonts.localhost` to `127.0.0.1 fonts.localhost.localdomain`, after this change jQuery worked. Is it worth a bugreport?